# TypeError: assertListEqual() missing 1 required positional argument: 'list2'

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing

while comparing 2 list with unittest

```
print(actualOptions)
print(expectedOptions)
unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual(actualOptions,expectedOptions)
```

the 2 list are printed the same as below:

```
['html', 'css', 'JavaScript', 'php']
['html', 'css', 'JavaScript', 'php']
```

but a TypeError is reported:

```
TypeError: assertListEqual() missing 1 required positional argument: 'list2'
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the `assertListEqual()` function is not static method.

You must create `TestCase` instance and call its `assertListEquals()` function.

Just like this:

```py
import unittest

actualOptions = ['html', 'css', 'JavaScript', 'php']
expectedOptions = ['html', 'css', 'JavaScript', 'php']

print(actualOptions)
print(expectedOptions)

tc = unittest.TestCase()
tc.assertListEqual(actualOptions, expectedOptions)

# Or simply like this:
# unittest.TestCase().assertListEqual(actualOptions, expectedOptions)
```